# Akka streams Source.repeat stops after 100 requests

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am working on the below stream processing system to grab frames from one source, process, and send to another. I'm using a combination of `akka-streams` and `akka-http` through their scapa api. The pipeline is very short but I can't seem to locate where the system decides to stop after precisely 100 requests to the endpoint.

```
object frameProcessor extends App {
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("VideoStreamProcessor")
  val decider: Supervision.Decider = _ => Supervision.Restart
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val dispatcher: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher
  val http = Http(system)
  val sourceConnectionFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Future[Http.OutgoingConnection]] = http.outgoingConnection(sourceUri)

  val byteFlow: Flow[HttpResponse, Future[ByteString], NotUsed] =
    Flow[HttpResponse].map(_.entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString.empty)(_ ++ _))

  Source.repeat(HttpRequest(uri = sourceUri))
    .via(sourceConnectionFlow)
    .via(byteFlow)
    .map(postFrame)
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
    .onComplete(_ => system.terminate())

  def postFrame(imageBytes: Future[ByteString]): Unit = {
    imageBytes.onComplete{
      case Success(res) => system.log.info(s"post frame. ${res.length} bytes")
      case Failure(_) => system.log.error("failed to post image!")
    }
  }
}
```

Fore reference, I'm using `akka-streams` version **2.5.19** and `akka-http` version **10.1.7**. No error is thrown, no error codes on the source server where the frames come from, and the program exits with error code 0.

My `application.conf` is as follows:

```
logging = "DEBUG"
```

Always 100 units processed.

Thanks!

### Edit

Added logging to the stream like so

```
.onComplete{
  case Success(res) => {
    system.log.info(res.toString)
    system.terminate()
  }
  case Failure(res) => {
    system.log.error(res.getMessage)
    system.terminate()
  }

}
```

Received a connection reset exception but this is inconsistent. The stream completes with `Done`.

### Edit 2

Using `.mapAsync(1)(postFrame)` I get the same `Success(Done)` after precisely 100 requests. Additionally, when I check the nginx server `access.log` and `error.log` there are only `200` responses.

I had to modify `postFrame` as follows to run `mapAsync`

```
def postFrame(imageBytes: Future[ByteString]): Future[Unit] = {
  imageBytes.onComplete{
    case Success(res) => system.log.info(s"post frame. ${res.length} bytes")
    case Failure(_) => system.log.error("failed to post image!")
  }
  Future(Unit)
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add logging to `.onComplete(_ => system.terminate())`?  It might be that the server just stops sending data after 100 frames.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Looks like the connection is reset by the peer host. I thought using a restart decider would've caused the stream to restart but that is not the case. Where would I catch that connection reset error? Not in this example, but in my code I am using a `RestartSource.onFailureWithBackoff` and it still craps out. Thanks for your response

Comment: Running a few times, there is not always a connection reset error. Instease i just get `Success(Done)`

Comment: @Andrew What happens if you use `mapAsync` instead of `map`?

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc i used `mapAsync` as described in edit 2 but it had no effect. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: One thing I just noticed (it might be just in your question code rather than in your real code), but is your `decider` used at all? I thought it is supposed to be passed to `ActorMaterializer` constructor.

Comment: @SergGr yes, I experimented using a `decider` in both the `dispatcher`and explicitly on the stream using `withAttributes` and neither seemed to have the right effect. I referred to the [supervision strategies](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-error.html#supervision-strategies) a lot! Appreciate the comment though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have found the answer on on the [Akka docs using delayed restarts with a backoff operator](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-error.html#delayed-restarts-with-a-backoff-operator). Instead of sourcing direct from an unstable remote connection, I use `RestartSource.withBackoff` and **not** `RestartSource.onFailureWithBackoff`. The modified stream looks like;

```
val restartSource = RestartSource.withBackoff(
  minBackoff = 100.milliseconds,
  maxBackoff = 1.seconds,
  randomFactor = 0.2
){ () =>
  Source.single(HttpRequest(uri = sourceUri))
    .via(sourceConnectionFlow)
    .via(byteFlow)
    .mapAsync(1)(postFrame)
}
restartSource
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
  .onComplete{
    x => {
      println(x)
      system.terminate()
    }
 }
```

I was not able to find the source of the problem but it seems this will work.